# Are there tenets of Rastafarianism that run counter to Baptist theology?

Tags: rastafarian

I am a Baptist and I have no desire to call myself a Rasta but I believe in some things they believe in such as living clean, peace, unity, etc. Is it wrong to identify with those things?

Many say that Rastafarianism isn't a religion but more a way of life. Would any of their practices (excluding calling [Haile Selassie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haile_Selassie) god) be considered sinful by a Baptist congregation?

Comment: In order to answer your question it will have to enumerate exactly what each article of Rastafarianism you wish us to compare, certainly some ideas are completely compatible with Christian teaching, but many are not. for that reason I am voting to close your question as too broad for this site. Please check out the help section for what makes a good question and what makes a good answer. As a new person it will be very helpful to take the tour of the site first.

Comment: In addition to what Cecil mentioned, in order to answer whether _anything_ is "wrong" according to Christianity we need to know which branch of Christianity or theological framework you identify with. You can try to [edit] this information into your question then maybe we can help you. [These meta posts](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+questions?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) also have tips on asking questions here you might find helpful.

Comment: is my edit better? and thank you for the feedback

Comment: @TG2012 yes, though keep in mind that this site is *not* a site for life advice. We can tell you what people believe, we won't (and shouldn't) tell you what to do. If you have questions about how you are living your life, whether something is a sin or not etc, we recommend talking to someone in the flesh, your pastor, other leaders in your church etc. Make sure it's someone you trust and whose opinion on spiritual things you respect.

Comment: @TG2012 there are several kinds of Baptist, it may help to specify

Comment: Your rewrite is somewhat better, but still a little too broad in that you need to specify what particulars you are asking about. for instance if you ask about living peacefully among your neighbors we can then quote the scriptures covering  that subject. Otherwise it is asking more for our opinions which we do not give. What I suggest is that you take wax eagle's sound advice and seek council with your Pastor, since if I read your question correctly, you seem to be seeking a basis on which to make a very personal decision.

Comment: "Emancipate yourselves from mental slavery,none but ourselves can free our minds." Bob Marley 1945-1981

Comment: It doesn't really seem fair to exclude Rastafarianism's view of Haile Selassie considering that it's the clearest and most obvious incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes down to it the rastafari have derived many things from christianity and judaeism. Some of the major points that make Rastafari diverse from your christian faith (exclluding calling haile selassie God) is that Rastafari often take up the Nazarite vow hence the dread locks, the Rastafari terminalogy such as, "I and I", "jah Rastafari"...etc., also its very important,to mention the extreme importance that, Rastas put upon marijuana and the huge role it plays in there faith and rituals, and the fact of the afrocentrism rastas perpetuate hold certain aspects of there faith, for instance many rastas believe themselves and african americans to be among the lost tribes of Israel, they refer to a book called the kaebra negaust as sacred account of King solomon forming a special bond with ethiopia by bearing a son from the ethiopian queen and creating a Solomonic dynasty after the prince took the throne of his mother.

Do these above mentioned things conflict with baptist christian practice? That will always be based upon opinion.